# Spacemacs org-mode faces

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

How do I turn off all of the custom faces used by Spacemacs `org-mode`? For example, the background colouring, the overlines, the bold faces etc.

I tried using the `Customize` sub-menu from the `Org` menu to set my own faces, and it added lines like:

```
'(org-level-1 ((t nil)))
```

to `custom-set-faces` in my `.dotspacemacs` file. However, this doesn't stop Spacemacs showing the top-level heading with a large bold font on a gray background. I find these visual decorations very distracting and just want to see the text that I type!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to disable all faces then you should deactivate `font-lock-mode` by doing `M-x font-lock-mode`.

You could configure it to happen automatically by adding an `org-mode-hook` as follows in the `user-config` section of your dotfile:

```lisp
(defun my-disable-font-lock ()
  (font-lock-mode 0))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-disable-font-lock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your cursor on the offending text, then in the top menu, *Options->Customize Emacs->Specific Face* and you will go directly to the one you want to change.